# Field bookRepository in com.code.service.BookServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.myAppp.code.respository.BookRepository' that could not be found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am receiving an error when I try to build/run a SpringBoot application as follows:

`Field bookRepository in com.myApp.code.service.BookServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.myApp.code.respository.BookRepository' that could not be found.`

The repository in question is:

```
package com.myApp.code.respository;

import com.myApp.code.model.Book;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long> {    
}
```

And in the service class I have the following:

```
package com.myApp.code.service;

import com.myApp.code.model.Book;
import com.myApp.code.respository.BookRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    @Service
    public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService {   

        @Autowired
        private BookRepository bookRepository;

        @Override
        public void list() {
            //return bookRepository.findAll();
            for (Book book : bookRepository.findAll()) {
                System.out.println(book.getTitle());
            }
        }
```

In the controller concerned I have:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="book")
public class BookController {

    @Autowired         
    private BookService bookService;    
    @Autowired   
    private PersonService personService;  
    @Autowired
    private BookValidator bookValidator;      

    private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    public BookController() {       
    }

    // Displays the catalogue.
    @RequestMapping(value="/catalogue", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model) {           
        LOG.info(BookController.class.getName() + ".catalogue() method called."); 

        // Populate catalogue.        
        bookService.list();      
//        model.addAttribute("books", books);   

        // Set view.                  
        return "/catalogue";               
    }
```

And in the Application.java file I have:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.myApp.code")
public class Application {

    private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass().getName());


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
```

The Book class is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BOOK")
public class Book implements Serializable {

    // Fields.
    @Id
    @Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="AUTHOR", nullable=false, length=50)
    private String author;

    @Column(name="TITLE", nullable=false, length=100)
    private String title;

    @Column(name="DESCRIPTION", nullable=false, length=500)
    private String description;

    @Column(name="ONLOAN", nullable=false, length=5)
    private String onLoan;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Person.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="Person_Id", nullable=true)    
    private Person person;
```

My Maven POM file is:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency> 

       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
            <version>10.14.2.0</version>
        </dependency>      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Can anyone tell me why I get this message? Class `BookRepository` exists after all.

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace please

Comment: Place your `Application` class in the `com.myApp.code` package and not a sub package.

Comment: @M Deinum. If you want to convert your comment to an answer, I will accept it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring boot will only look for repositories, entities and components within the same package or a subpackage of the main class (`Application`). You already added the `@ComponentScan` to point to the other package, but you should also add the package to both `@EntityScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories`, for example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.myApp.code") // Add this
@EntityScan("com.myApp.code") // Add this 
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.myApp.code")
public class Application {
    // ...
}
```

This is also being mentioned in [JpaRepository not implemented/injected when in separate package from componentscan](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25609164).

Alternatively, [as mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50676750/field-bookrepository-in-com-code-service-bookserviceimpl-required-a-bean-of-type#comment88363220_50676750), you can put the main class in `com.myApp.code` itself.

> Place your `Application` class in the `com.myApp.code` package and not a sub package. – M. Deinum

By doing that, you can remove all three annotations:

```java
@SpringBootApplication // Other annotations can be removed
public class Application {
    // ...
}
```